# Visual C++ linker crashes (VS2008 SP1)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

The following piece of code, used to generates primes, compiles and runs as expected when running debug, but always seems to crash the inker when building in Release mode:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> class PrimeGen {
    struct Elim {
        T p ;
        T e ;
    } ;

    class Elim_cmp {
    public:
        bool operator()(const Elim& e1, const Elim& e2) { return e1.e > e2.e; }
    } ;

    std::vector<Elim> elim_heap ;
    T last ;

public:
    PrimeGen() {
        Elim e0 = { 2, 4 } ;
        elim_heap.reserve(1024) ;
        elim_heap.push_back(e0) ;
        last = 2 ;
    }

    T next() {
        T n = last ;
        bool prime;
        do {
            n ++ ;
            prime = true ;
            while(n == elim_heap.front().e) {
                if(prime) prime = false ;
                std::pop_heap(elim_heap.begin(), elim_heap.end(), Elim_cmp()) ;
                Elim& elim = elim_heap.back() ;
                elim.e = elim.p + n ;
                std::push_heap(elim_heap.begin(), elim_heap.end(), Elim_cmp()) ;
            }
        } while(!prime) ;
        Elim e = { n, 2*n } ;
        elim_heap.push_back( e ) ;
        std::push_heap(elim_heap.begin(), elim_heap.end(), Elim_cmp()) ;
        return last = n ;
    }
} ;

int main()
{
    using namespace std ;
    PrimeGen<unsigned int> pgen ;
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        cout << pgen.next() << endl ;
    }
    system("pause") ;
}
```

Can anyone see why this would be happening? Or have I encountered one of those rare instances where the compiler, and not the code, is to blame?

The error I get is as follows:

```
error PRJ0002 : Error result -1073741819 returned from 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\mt.exe'.
```

If anyone else who's running Visual Studio would take the time to try and build the code in release mode (I've removed any external dependencies, so it should just be c&p) I'd be much obliged.

**UPDATE**: On further review, it seems like mt.exe keeps crashing for me in Release mode even for simple "Hello World" code, so there must be a problem with my installation. I'm going to reinstall everything which should hopefully fix this. Moderators, feel free to close this question.

Comment: Builds cleanly for x86 and x64 release using VC++ 2010 SP1.

Comment: I was able to compile/link this (VS 2008 9.0.21022.8) with no problem. I didn't expect that because I have some multi-project solutions which frequently crash the linker however it's not repeatable for me - frequently a second F7 builds whatever failed the first time without further errors.

Comment: mt.exe merely embeds the manifest. Perhaps some files end up being locked? Could you try to clean the solution (make sure all generated files are gone) and then do a rebuild?

Comment: Built OK with VC++ Express 2010 in both debug & release, FWIW.

Comment: Change your update to an answer, and later you can accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Some program, such as an anti-virus program, is scanning the file.exe at the same time as the linker is attempting to embed the manifest file.